# How to log every error in file you get in cmd

Tags: python, logging, error-handling, try-catch, traceback

I tried try catch block in my python script but my team lead wants to log every error which can occure i cannot write try catch every line do anyone know better way to do this? currently im using try catch and logger module for logging certain comparisions she says she wants to log everytime error happens

only getting log of try catch block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need to do is log when an error happens, then I'd just wrap the entire script (or at least the part that is going to produce the error) in a single try-catch block that simply writes to a file whenever an error occurs.

```py
try:
    # all your code here
except:
    with open("log.txt", "a") as fp:
        fp.write("error")
        fp.write(data)
```

Comment: hey yea thats helpfull what is data in there?

Comment: so i did this look 
try:
    # all your code here
except Exception as e:
    logger.info(e)

Comment: @ManavSuhange data is just whatever data you want to log to the file (I assumed you want to log more then just "error" for each issue after all. You could just log the problematic variables there, or something like `f"{type(e).__name__}({e})"` which would log the type of error (though except would need to be `except Exception as e:` instead